# AngularJS - How to get a single element from a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I've been seen this question answered differently in other posts, but the goals seemed different, beside some of the solutions I still don't get it. What I need is to show only a single item, once you click on its title. For instance:

JSON file:

```
[
    {
    "section": "Certifications",
    "courses": [
      {
        "title": "Certificate 1",
        "code": "SIT10213",
        "requisite": false,
        "cost": "110",
        "duration": "5h"
      },{
        "title": "Certificate 2",
        "code": "YYX",
        "requisite": "Course X",
        "cost": "150",
        "duration": "172 hours"
      },{
        "title": "Certificate 3",
        "code": "XXY",
        "requisite": "Course Y",
        "cost": "210",
        "duration": "1 day"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "section": "Qualifications",
    "courses": [
      {
        "title": "Bar Operations",
        "code": "SXW",
        "requisite": false,
        "cost": "120",
        "duration": "97–107 hours in total"
       },
       {
        "title": "RSA",
        "code": "YZX",
        "requisite": false,
        "cost": "100",
        "duration": "97–107 hours in total"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the HTML what I'm trying to do is:

1. The app lists the links for each sections/categories;
2. "Show all" should simply list them all
   (I haven't worked on this one yet)
3. You click on the section and it lists the courses available under it.
   (Up until here I managed to get it working.)
4. User clicks on the course title and the details of that particular course is displayed. 
   (Here is where the nested arrays trick me. Is there such a thing as courseArray.section[parentIndex].course[$index].title?)

Here's a Plnkr version - started but never fixed:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JRIyQLuRfVslVjr5fFSY?p=preview

Any light on this is much appreciated.
Best, San

Comment: Seems like you have a few unnecessary ng-repeat.  Try assign a selected course to a $scope.variable and use that variable to bind to the course detail section.

Comment: Sorry Will not sure if I understand what you mean. I've came up with a workaround described below, maybe is what you're saying I'm assigning the course code to a variable and then filtering it in the ngRepeat - also this time I'm only using one as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure whether this is the best approach but it does what I need. 
I've added the course code as a parameter to the ngClick function, when you click the course link. When fetching the courses using ng-repeat, I'm using "filter : courseCode" to only display the one course that matches the code sent above.
Hope that helps someone else too. Cheers